What closing reasons should be added?
The dialog window for closing a question, under A community reason, only lists this reason:

This question does not appear to be about Esperanto language, within the scope defined in the help center.

Since the help center has a short list of questions that should not be asked, that closing reason is technically correct, but there should be more specific closing reasons. (It would help to understand why a question is closed, without reading the part of the help center about the allowed topics.)
Other Stack Exchange language sites use the following closing reasons.
English Language Learners

Basic questions on spelling, meaning or pronunciation are off-topic as they should be answered using a dictionary. See: Policy for questions that are entirely answerable with a dictionary


This question should include more details than have been provided here. Please edit to add the research you have done in your efforts to answer the question, or provide more context. See: Details, Please.


Questions asking for someone to find and correct errors or improve the phrasing are considered requests for proofreading and are off-topic. Please edit your question to focus on something in particular that you are unsure about; if that's not possible, see websites for proofreading instead.

English Language & Usage

Answered by a dictionary
Questions that can be easily answered by consulting a reputable online dictionary should be closed with this reason unless the question includes an explanation of why the dictionary wasn't helpful. When using this close reason, consider providing a link to a relevant reference in a comment.


Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: About single word requests


Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.

Italian Language

This website is not a translation service: questions that ask to translate a single sentence, without further motivation, are considered off-topic. If you are uncertain about a certain word or nuance of meaning, please edit the question mentioning the exact issue, including your attempts at translation, and describing your doubts.


Questions asking if a given text is correct are considered off-topic on this site. If it is possible, please reformulate your question so that it asks about a specific doubt you have rather than asking to proofread a long text.

French Language

We are not a text translation or proofreading service. If you're translating into French, be specific about the word or expression you want help with, and explain the meaning and provide context. If you're asking about the correctness of a sentence, tell us which specific word or construction you are unsure about.


Dictionary-lookup question.
This question asks about the meaning of a word or phrase that can be found by looking it up in a dictionary. Do not vote to close dictionary-lookup questions if looking up the word or phrase does not clarify the sentence or passage in which it occurs - e.g. idioms, metaphors.


Blatantly off-topic
This question has nothing to do with French language.

German Language

Can be answered just as well by a dictionary, thesaurus, or conjugation table
The only answers we can post to this question reproduce a dictionary entry or similar. The question neither elaborates why such a resource did not help nor is it obvious. Do not vote to close questions only because they can be answered by grammar books. Also see this FAQ for close voters.


Bulk proofreading or translation request
This question asks for the translation, proofreading, or spell checking of a text. It does not ask for help with a single issue within that text. Phrases, idioms, and similar are such single issues; questions on them are welcome in general, i.e., unless they should be closed for a different reason.


Needs expertise in a language other than German
This is a translation request to German where the problem is understanding the term in the source language or this is a translation request from German where understanding the German term is not the problem (and its meaning is not so intricate that it’s difficult to describe with other words). Also see this FAQ for close voters.


Blatantly off-topic
This question has nothing to do with German language.

Japanese Language

Questions asking for translations, transcriptions or proofreading are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not to provide a bulk translation service nor to proofread your translations or transcriptions. See: We don't do translations.


This question was caused by a simple spelling mistake, misreading, or typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. For more information, see our meta discussion on "typo questions".


Questions seeking resources or advice about learning Japanese are off-topic here, but you may find our list of resources for learning Japanese helpful.


Blatantly off-topic
This question has nothing to do with the Japanese language.

The closing reasons common to two or more sites seems to be about:

Questions which can be answered by reading a dictionary
Translation and proof-reading questions

Which closing reasons should we have?
The closing reasons that is possible to add are just three. They should be the most commonly used closing reason. For other closing reasons, users with enough privileges can enter a custom reason.
